# Python: Understanding loops

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I'm super new to Python, I think this isn't a problem with my syntax, but with my understanding...(and I'm sure there's an easier way to do this, but right now I really just want some help with what is wrong with my understanding of loops)

Considering some code that goes roughly like...

```
for k, v in dict1.iteritems():
    if v not in dict2.keys():
        print "adding %s to dict2" % v
        dict2[v] = "whatever"
```

My loop cycles through the "if" for every single key in dict1, I can tell because of the print statement. It's as though the for loop uses the original definition of dict2 each time, and doesn't consider whatever happened in the last iteration.

I had expected that once I went through the for loop once, with a unique value from dict1, any duplicate values from dict1 would skip the if step of the loop because that value was already added to dict2 in a previous iteration. Is that incorrect?

Thanks so much!

Joe

more context: hi, here is what I actually have (first thing I've ever written, so maybe it would be helpful to me if you critiqued the whole thing!) I have a file listing employees and their designated "work unit" (substitute the word "work unit" for "team" if it helps), and I figured how to import that into a dictionary. Now I want to turn that into a dictionary of "work units" as keys, with an associated employee as the value. For now it doesn't matter which employee, I just am trying to figure out how to get a dictionary containing 1 key for each work unit). what I have so far...

```
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
r = sheet.nrows
i = 1
employees = {}

'''Importing employees into a employees dictionary'''
while i < r:
    hrid = sheet.row_values(i,0,1)
    name = sheet.row_values(i,1,2)
    wuid = sheet.row_values(i,2,3)
    wuname = sheet.row_values(i,3,4)
    wum = sheet.row_values(i,4,5)
    parentwuid = sheet.row_values(i,5,6)
    employees[str(i)] = hrid, name, wuid, wuname, wum, parentwuid
    i += 1

'''here's where I create workunits dictionary and try to begin to populate''' 
workunits = {}

for k, v in employees.iteritems():
        if v[2] not in workunits.keys():
            print "Adding to %s to the dictionary" % (v[2])
            workunits[str(v[2])] = v[1]
```

Solution: OK, finally got there...it's just because I hadn't called str() on v[2] in my if statement. Thanks all!

Comment: Can we have more context of the code block?

Comment: `dict.keys()` is being created each time in your loop, it's not possible that it'll use the original definition(if it was updated). Apart from that the call to `keys()` is redundant and in-efficient for py2.x.

Comment: Demo: http://ideone.com/8fvF5n

Comment: Your code is completely different from your example:
`workunits[str(k)] = v[2]` should be `workunits[v[2]] = 'whatever'` according to your first example. You never added `v[2]` to `workunits`, so `v[2] not in workunits.keys()` is going to be `True`.

Comment: Ugh, Ashwini, you're completely right. What I put in the edit isn't actually what I had, I fiddled around with it in response to Stephans answer and forgot to change it back. 
I did have workunits[v[2]] = 'whatever' and that was where I started with this problem. Will review your demo and see if I can figure it out from there (and I'll fix my edits) thanks!

Comment: OK, finally got there...it's just because I hadn't called str() on v[2] in my if statement. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

You're checking to see if `v` (a value) is in dict2's keys, but then adding it as a key.  Is that what you want it to do?

If maybe you meant to copy elements over this might be what you meant to do:

```
if k not in dict2.keys():
    print "adding %s to dict2" % v
    dict2[k] = v
```

Comment: isn't the line:
    dict2[v] = "whatever"
adding v as the key and "whatever" as the value?

Comment: yes, i'm not sure what you're trying to do, but it wont prevent multiple additions. @user2713292

Comment: I want to dict2 to contain a key for every unique value in dict1

Answer (score 0):

You mention in your comment "I want to dict2 to contain a key for every unique value in dict1".

There's a compact syntax for getting the result you want.

```
d_1 = {1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6}
d_2 = {v: "whatever" for v in d_1.itervalues()}
```

However, this doesn't address you concern about about duplicates.

What you could do is make a `set` of the values in d_1 (no duplicates) and then create d_2 from that:

```
values_1 = set(d_1.itervalues())
d_2 = {v: "whatever" for v in values_1}
```

Another option is to use the `fromkeys` method, but to my eye this isn't as clear as the dictionary comprehension.

```
d_2 = {}.fromkeys(set(d_1.itervalues()))
```

Unless you have reason to believe that processing duplicates is slowing down your code unacceptably, I'd say you should use the most direct method to express what you want.

For your application of converting the employee_to_team dictionary to a team_to_employee dictionary, you could then do:

```
team_to_employee = {v: k for k, v in employee_to_team.iteritems()}
```

This because you don't care which employee gets represented and this method will just overwrite each time a duplicate is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

This question is more for codereview than for SO, but

```
for k, v in dict1.iteritems(): # here's you iterating through tuples like (key, value) from dict1
    if v not in dict2.keys():  # list of dict2 keys created each time and you iterating through the whole list trying to find v
        print "adding %s to dict2" % v
        dict2[v] = "whatever"
```

you can simplify (and improve performance) your code like

```
for k, v in dict1.iteritems(): # here's you iterating through tuples like (key, value) from dict1
    if v not in dict2:         # just check if v is already in dict2
        print "adding %s to dict2" % v
        dict2[v] = "whatever"
```

or even

```
dict2 = {v:"whatever" for v in dict1.values()}
```

Comment: thanks for the point about codereview, I'll make sure I post there next time